# Calling PowerShell From C#

Tags: c#, powershell, automation

I am using `System.Management.Automation` DLL which allows me to call PowerShell within my C# application like so:

```
PowerShell.Create().AddScript("Get-Process").Invoke();
```

What I am trying to do is call PowerShell but supply the input list.  For example, in:

```
1, 2, 3 | ForEach-Object { $_ * 2 }
```

I am trying to supply the left hand side `1, 2, 3` when invoking:

```
// powershell is a PowerShell Object
powershell.Invoke(new [] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

However this does not work.  The **workaround** I came up with was using `ForEach-Object` and then passing the array as an `InputObject` with the `{ $_ }` as the `Process`:

```
// create powershell object
var powershell = PowerShell.Create();

// input array 1, 2, 3
Command inputCmd = new Command("ForEach-Object");
inputCmd.Parameters.Add("InputObject", new [] { 1, 2, 3 });
inputCmd.Parameters.Add("Process", ScriptBlock.Create("$_"));
powershell.Commands.AddCommand(inputCmd);

// ForEach-Object { $_ * 2 }
Command outputCmd = new Command("ForEach-Object");
outputCmd.Parameters.Add("Process", ScriptBlock.Create("$_ * 2"));
powershell.Commands.AddCommand(outputCmd);

// invoke
var result = powershell.Invoke();
```

Although the above is working code is there any way of using `Invoke` passing in the input array because I would have though that this would be desirable way of calling it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A little bit late but:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("a", new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
ps.AddScript("$a");
ps.AddCommand("foreach-object");
ps.AddParameter("process", ScriptBlock.Create("$_ * 2"));
Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

returns:

```
2
4
6
```

Comment: This works but you are passing `1,2,3` as a string rather than an array i.e. `new int[] { 1,2,3 }`.  The second one is needed if I am to pass structured data to the pipeline.

Comment: @TahirHassan The only way I know to pass .net object created is using `SessionStateProxy.SetVariable(string name, object value)`. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: You have answered my question on how to start the pipeline with an array (without passing it to `ForEach-Object` using the `InputObject` parameter as described in my question). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have done my research and `PowerShell.Invoke( IEnumerable )` will set the `InputObject` of the first command in the list.  Therefore instead of setting `InputObject` on `inputCmd` above, we can instead pass it through the `Invoke` method.  We still need the first `ForEach-Object` call to pass the input array to.

Comment: This is genius! I would never look for it there!