# redirect powershell output c++

Tags: c++, powershell, cmd

How I can redirect powershell output to my c++ program? Now I am adding `| Out-File "MyFileName"` to command, then read this file in program. How I can do that without file? I know I can do this by using C# or CLI, but I need something like pipe, that’s perfectly worked with cmd.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What do you exactly mean with 'powershell output'. What are you _exactly_ trying to achieve? And what have you _exactly_ tried so far?

Comment: @dingalapadum I'm try to run powershell command from my program, and save everything that powershell outputs in console, in memory, without saving output in file.

Comment: @NickEatMore if you are trying to run powershell from within your executable, then this is certainly not redirection. Redirection is, when you pipe the output of powershell to your executable.

Comment: @SelcukCihan yes, i am use my program to execute powershell with some params, and then collect all powershell output. In this moment, i am using file, but i wanna do without it.

Comment: Googling for c++ powershell yielded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634220/c-and-powershell check if suits you

Comment: @SelcukCihan alredy try it. Cli didn't suits, because it requires .Net

Answer (score 0):

Pipe perfectly works with native programs, as a proof check this out:

```
ps | less
```

which is AFAIK the same as

```
ps | out-string | less
```

Less is is a C++ Linux tool. You can get less from [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/): `cinst less`.