# Calling PowerShell cmdlet from C# throws CommandNotFoundException

Tags: c#, powershell, invoke

I'm trying to call the `Add-AppxPackage` cmdlet from C#.  I found the MSDN article on [running PowerShell from C# code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I have referenced the System.Management.Automation assembly and have tried the following code snippets, all of which result in the same exception when trying to call powerShell.Invoke():

> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException was unhandled
>
> The term 'Add-AppxPackage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Snippet 1:

```
var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.AddCommand(string.Format("Add-AppxPackage '{0}'", appxFilePath));

foreach (PSObject result in powerShell.Invoke())
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

I understand why this doesn't work, since I shouldn't be providing parameters in the AddCommand() function.

Snippet 2:

```
var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.AddCommand("Add-AppxPackage");
powerShell.AddParameter("Path", appxFilePath);

foreach (PSObject result in powerShell.Invoke())
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Snippet 3:

```
var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.AddCommand("Add-AppxPackage");
powerShell.AddArgument(appxFilePath);

foreach (PSObject result in powerShell.Invoke())
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

My C# project targets .Net 4.5, and if I do powerShell.AddCommand("Get-Host") it works and the Version it returns back is 4.0.  Add-AppxPackage was added in v3.0 of PowerShell, so the command should definitely exist, and it works fine if I manually run this command from the Windows PowerShell command prompt.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Any suggestions are appreciated.

-- Update --

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067971/invoking-powershell-cmdlets-from-c-sharp) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251076/calling-powershell-from-c-sharp), and realized there is a AddScript() function, so I tried this:

Snippet 4:

```
var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.AddScript(string.Format("Add-AppxPackage '{0}'", appxFilePath));

var results = powerShell.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

And it does not throw an exception, but it also doesn't install the metro app, and the "results" returned from powerShell.Invoke() are empty, so I'm still at a loss...

-- Update 2 --

So I decided that I would try just creating a new PowerShell process to run my command, so I tried this:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("PowerShell", string.Format("-Command Add-AppxPackage '{0}'; $key = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp')", appxFilePath)));
```

but it still throws the same error that Add-AppxPackage is not a recognized cmdlet.

### ANSWER

If you follow the long comment thread on robert.westerlund's answer, you will see that for some reason when running/launched from Visual Studio, PowerShell was not including all of the PSModulePaths that it does when running straight from a PowerShell command prompt, so many modules are not present. The solution was to find the absolute path of the module that I needed (the appx module in my case) using:

```
(Get-Module appx -ListAvailable).Path
```

And then import that module before trying to call one of its cmdlets. So this is the C# code that worked for me:

```
var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.AddScript(string.Format(@"Import-Module 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Appx\Appx.psd1'; Add-AppxPackage '{0}'", appxFilePath));
var results = powerShell.Invoke();
```

### UPDATED ANSWER

You can see from [this other post I opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696155/powershell-does-not-load-all-psmodulepaths-when-running-from-visual-studio-cod), that the problem was with a bug in a Visual Studio extension (in my case StudioShell) causing not all of the PSModulePaths to be loaded. After uninstalling that extension all of the modules were loaded correctly and I no longer needed to manually import the module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PowerShell there is a difference between terminating errors (which stops the execution) and non-terminating errors (which are just written to the error stream).

If you want to create a non-terminating error in a function of your own, just use the `Write-Error` cmdlet. If you want to create a terminating error, use the `Throw` keyword. You can read more about these concepts if you run `Get-Help Write-Error`, `Get-Help about_Throw` and `Get-Help about_Try_Catch_Finally`.

Using the `Add-AppxPackage` with a non existing package is a non terminating error and will thus be written to the error stream, but no execution halting exception will be thrown. The following code tries to add a non existing package and then writes the error to the console.

```
var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.AddScript("Add-AppxPackage NonExistingPackageName");

// Terminating errors will be thrown as exceptions when calling the Invoke method. 
// If we want to handle terminating errors, we should place the Invoke call inside a try-catch block.
var results = powerShell.Invoke();

// To check if a non terminating error has occurred, test the HadErrors property
if (powerShell.HadErrors)
{
    // The documentation for the Error property states that "The command invoked by the PowerShell 
    // object writes information to this stream whenever a nonterminating error occurs."
    foreach (var error in powerShell.Streams.Error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error);
    }
}
else
{
    foreach(var package in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(package);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be abe to use this to read the non terminating error you are most likely receiving when calling the `Add-AppxPackage` function.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it looks like this is a terminating error; powerShell.Invoke() throws a CommandNotFoundException, so it never hits any code after that (unless I wrap it in a try-catch). If I do wrap it in a try-catch then powerShell.HadErrors is true, but powerShell.Streams.Error is empty. The problem is not that the .appx file does not exist, but that it does not recognize the Add-AppxPackage command, even though it is using PowerShell v4.0 which does have this command.

Comment: In your `Snippet 4` you mention that no exception was thrown but no application was installed. That was the snippet I based my sample on. Has something changed; are you receiving an exception in that snippet too now?

Comment: Ah, ok. I just ran it again using the code from Snippet 4 and you are right; when I run it this way it is a non-terminating error (i.e. no exception is thrown). powerShell.Streams.Error contains the same error message though that Add-AppxPackage is not a recognized cmdlet.

Comment: Windows 8.1 64-bit. Even if I replace my .appx filepath with an invalid path, like "C:\DoesNotExist.txt", the same errors are thrown that Add-AppxPackage is not recognized.

Comment: What do you get if you do `Get-Module AppX` (or including the `-ListAvailable` switch)? Does it find the module at all?

Comment: And also, which PowerShell version does it state that you are running, if you check the `PSVersion` property on the `$PSVersionTable` variable (`Get-Host` is not interesting, the potentially interesting information lies in the `$PSVersionTable` variable)?

Comment: Using 'powerShell.AddScript("$PSVersionTable.PSVersion");' returns back '4.0', but 'Get-Module appx' does not return back anything; but it does if I run it directly in a PowerShell command prompt. So it seems that the Appx module is not loaded for some reason, and using 'Import-Module Appx' returns an error message saying that no valid module file could be found. Also, using 'Get-Module -All' does not return anything back either, so it looks like none of the required modules are loaded.

Comment: If it does exist normally, then perhaps the problem is that you don't have the correct environment variables available? Could you compare the results of `(Get-Item Env:\PSModulePath).Value -Split ";"`? And also, could you try loading the AppX module using an absolute path (I think it should be at `Import-Module C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Appx\Appx.psd1`, the path can be found by doing `(get-module appx -ListAvailable).Path` in the PowerShell command prompt where you could find the module in question) and see if that works?

Comment: Looks like you are right; from code the only PSModulePath is the one in my user's documents folder, but from a regular powershell prompt it includes 6 different paths, one of which is `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`. Changing to import the module using the full absolute path and then using Add-AppxPackage worked :) Thanks so much! I wonder why when I run from VS 2013 it doesn't load all of the module paths though? I tried both running VS as admin and not, and get the same results, and $Env:UserProfile is the same in VS as in the regular PowerShell prompt.