# PowerShell does not load all PSModulePaths when running from Visual Studio / Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

As you can see from [my answer on my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488780/calling-powershell-cmdlet-from-c-sharp-throws-commandnotfoundexception), for some reason when I run PowerShell from code in Visual Studio, either by calling [powershell.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or by starting a new PowerShell process, it does not include all of the [PSModulePaths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that are included when I manually startup a Windows PowerShell command prompt.

If I do `(Get-Item Env:\PSModulePath).Value -Split ';'` in a regular Windows PowerShell command prompt I get the following 7 paths:

```
C:\Users\Dan Schroeder\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\MpProvider\
C:\Program Files (x86)\\Code Owls LLC
```

However, if I run it from code I get the following 3 paths:

```
C:\Users\Dan Schroeder\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\
C:\Users\Dan Schroeder\Documents\WindowsPowershell\Modules
C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Owls LLC\StudioShell\bin\\..\\..
```

Why are these so different? Since when I run from code it doesn't include `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`, tons of the default built-in cmdlets are not available (e.g. `Get-Date`, `Test-Path`, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem, which was hidden in my question. I uninstalled [StudioShell](https://studioshell.codeplex.com/) (a Visual Studio PowerShell extension) and everything works correctly now. It looks like there is a bug in that extension.

In my question you can see that it is the last PSModulePath listed when I ran from Visual Studio, and that it has a relative path, where the rest of them have an absolute path.

I'll open a new bug for StudioShell to get this fixed up.

Comment: I've created a bug for this issue at https://studioshell.codeplex.com/workitem/77