# Running powershell from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Hey guys I am newish to C#.  I know powershell.  I am trying to figure out how to run a powershell script from a c# program.  I have below working as a test program for myself.  However when i try and put in more complex scripts ones that can include GUI windows that should pop up nothing seems to run.  Am i on the right track to figuring this out? I have also noticed that the semi colon after each line was needed to run the script correctly in C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            using (PowerShell PS = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PS.AddScript("$file = \"C:\\test\\csharp.txt\";"+
                "Set-Content -path $file -value \"testc\";");
                PS.Invoke();
            }



        }//end of main
 }//end of class
}//end of namespace
```

Comment: There's a good tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

Comment: thanks i was reading that page earlier

Answer (score 0):

Only the UI thread can do UI operations. From what I can see, your PS.Invoke() creates its own thread, and I'm not finding anything that would allow you to promote it to the UI thread.

Comment: ok so i couldn't use any kind of UI with in powershell?  i would have to intertwine it with C# gui?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the normal pattern people use. This shows C# capturing the output of a .Invoke() and then outputting it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251076/calling-powershell-from-c-sharp