# Add 365 groups to an expiration policy from c#

Tags: azure-active-directory

I can see its possible to set expiration on groups via PowerShell. However I haven’t found any IP on adding specific groups to an expiration policy from c#. Any ideas how this can be performed? Ultimately through the graph API would be great.

[Add retention to groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-lifecycle)

New-AzureADMSGroupLifecyclePolicy -GroupLifetimeInDays 365 -ManagedGroupTypes All -AlternateNotificationEmails emailaddress@contoso.com

Comment: There seems to be an ActiveDS Com library that can be used for this. Looks like there's a related thread on this. You might be able to manually set maxPwdAge + pwdLastSet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764327/active-directory-user-password-expiration-date-net-ou-group-policy

Comment: The post about settings a users password and expiration? I am looking for 365 group retention policies. Is this related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [Group API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/grouplifecyclepolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0), the Graph API currently (as of Jan-2019) does support setting group lifecycle info.

If your requirement is purely about being able to do the above via C#, why now [PowerShell.Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251076/calling-powershell-from-c-sharp) the above command from your c# app?

Comment: The first link is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks! Number two is an option, but not a beautiful one :D